# JFROG Artifactory OSS - Nuget Package source Type is disabled

Tags: repository, artifactory, nuget-package, nuget-server

How do I enable the NuGet Package source Type on creating Local/Remote/Virtual Repository?

I have installed **JFROG Artifactory OSS** version(7.35.2) and when I'm trying to create Local/Remote/Virtual Repositories for NuGet, but I can't able to choose NuGet from package source type. FYR attached screenshot.

[image: Jfrog - Repository Type Selection]

If this option is not available with Artifactory OSS version, then suggest the way to do upload/downloading NuGet Packages with JFrog.

And forget to update, when I have tried with JFrog Cloud version, there I can able to use NuGet package Source Type.

Comment: @all - Just now i came to know, in Artifactory OSS version we have only 5 Types of Package Source Type[Generic, Gradle, Ivy, Maven & SBT]. So can anyone suggest is there any way to upload/download Nuget packages in JFrog.

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory OSS supports Maven, Gradle, Ivy, SBT, Generic package types as per this [confluence page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix) and hence you are not able to view Nuget options in OSS.

You might have tried JFrog cloud Pro version where it comes with license and you will be able to view all package types. You will need a minimum Pro license to use the Nuget package type.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the quick update. 

I'm looking around for Open Source artifactory with on-primes support as like JFrog Cloud Version.

Can you please suggest is there any other Open Source Artifactory to support Nuget?